# How to flash a bootloader onto the STM32WLE

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx, swd

I am currently designing a custom PCB with this board:
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wle5jb.html

I cannot find any mentioning that it comes with a factory installed bootloader. I would like to program it over SWD.

Do I need to flash and if yes, how?
These seem to be good ressources for me:
https://www.electronicshub.org/how-to-upload-stm32f103c8t6-usb-bootloader/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STM32WLE5xx has 2x USART and 2x SPI bootloaders. You can find more or less complete list of system bootloaders per MCU family in [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Which means, you do not have to program your own. You can use downloadable utilities with system one. It seems this bootloader does not require an access to boot pins, according to "pattern 13" in the same document.

Comment: does that mean that I can already just flash my code using STM32CubeMX over USART or SPI or that I need to flash bootloader over that peripherals? I have an STlink v2 here that I can use to program over SWD, do I need different pins for bootloader flashing and for SWD programming?

Comment: SWD programming has nothing to do with bootloader. SWD interface allows you to program anything including your own bootloader. If you have access to SWDIO, SWCLK and NRST pins you can use STLink right away to flash your code. To use bootloader via USART or SPI you need an access to corresponding pins, an adapter and flashing utility.

Comment: thank you that clarified it.